# garage wiring problem

Tags: electrical

I have 3 wires coming into a 3 way switch. I connected the hot black wire to the brass screw on the left side of the switch. I connected the red traveler wire to the black screw on the right side of the switch  opposite the brass screw. I connected the white traveler wire to the brass screw on the top of the right side of the switch. The five lights in the circuit will then go on and off with the operation of the switch. The light fixtures are wired to the switch utilizing the white and red traveler wires. My problem is I cannot get the other 3 way switch to function no matter what wiring combination I try. I would like to know the correct way to wire the second switch. Two things to note. There were two 4 way switches in the circuit. I took those switches out of the circuit by wiring the two red wires together, in each box, and doing the same with the white wires. The other note is that there is no current going to the second switch no matter how I connect the wires. Am I not connecting a load to the circuit at the second switch?

Comment: Can you sketch a wiring diagram and add that to your question?  It would be a lot easier to follow.  Plus, the exercise of diagramming it often makes the issue clear before you're even done with your sketch.

Answer (score 3):

The black screw on a 3-way switch is the common, and the brass screws are the travelers.  It sounds like you wired up the switch incorrectly.